# Basic Library System in Prolog

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

I want to make a basic library management system in prolog. The program should answer queries like which book is issued by which student and which date book will be returned. I want guidance in terms what exact components i need to learn for it (as I am very much new to prolog), i wanna develop it rapidly as i dun have time to learn the whole thing. I will be using visual prolog 7.3

Thanks in Advance 
MGD

Comment: Removed the swi-prolog and sicstus-prolog tags as they aren't relevant. Visual Prolog is different from either of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us much of an idea what your programming background is, so I've interpolated a couple of comments below to suggest what existing experience might help in doing parts of the Visual-Prolog application asked about.

With Visual-Prolog you have to begin with user-interface design, something that I frankly found discouraging for playing around with the Prolog coding.  Think of the "window" elements you want: perhaps an input field to input a user name and another input field to enter a book title, with some buttons for "search" as your "program should answer queries" spec suggests.  The output will contain information about whether a book is checked out, when it is due, etc.

Then the functional part of your design can begin.  Visual-Prolog asks you to declare certain things: domains (equivalent to datatypes in other languages) and predicates (the names relations and the domains to which their various arguments apply, roughly the equivalent to routines in other languages).

Your library application sounds like it is similar to a database, a "knowledge-base" containing information about users, books, and the relationship between them (e.g. this user has this book checked out), possibly with some history (who checked out a book when, and when was it returned).

Since you want to "develop it rapidly", you will probably want to start with a very simple set of domains and predicates.  Perhaps "user" and "book" are the basic domains to start with, and **checkOut/2** the basic predicate (indicating the fact that a particular user currently has the particular book).  Then you will probably need to add (at least) the feature of storing the book's return date.  This kind of design will be easier if you've done some relational database development before.

Connecting the user-interface (UI) to the "knowledge-base" of library users & books is a matter of writing predicates that serve as event-handlers for the visual elements of the UI.  This is somewhat easier if you are familiar with Visual Basic.  In any case you can "stub out" the event handlers while you are building the "look and feel" part of the UI, replacing them with substantive implementations as your design moves into developing the "knowledge-base".

Comment: Hardmath, Thanks alot :) ... it was a great help from u !!!! ... i am considering all the tips and now m almost at the verge to finalize it.